# Why does this conditional statement evaluate to true?

Tags: java

i am new to programming and currently following the mooc.fi course on java programming and have a quick question regarding this [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE9Yd.png)

In the section !(number > 0 && number < 10) why does 10 evaluate to true? My thought process is that the statement 10 is not greater than zero should evaluate to false and since this is an and statement that the whole statement should evaluate to false. Thanks

Comment: because you ask the negative (using the !). It does return false, but you ask for the negative of the result, so, false becomes true.

Comment: because `!` is negating the result. `(number > 0 && number < 10)` would return false for number=10 and `!` negates that false into a true

Comment: 10 > 0 > true, 10 < 10 > false.
AND of them results to false then you negate it to true

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down and understand.

```
!(number > 0 && number < 10)
```

Here, `number = 10`

```
!(10 > 0 && 10 < 10)
= !(true && false)
= !false
= true
```

`!false` means `not false` which is `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it is very easy to understand now. Sorry if this was an overly simple question.